# Does $\Sigma_1$-separation over $L_\alpha$ implies admissibility?

Tags: logic, set-theory

[Inspired by the following tweet](https://twitter.com/DaiskeIkegami/status/1574502010636111872), I tried to prove the following statement:

> If $\alpha>\omega$ is a limit ordinal and $L_\alpha\models \Sigma_1\text{-Separation}$. Then $L_\alpha\models \mathsf{KP}$.

The only axiom we need to verify is $\Delta_0$-Collection. Since $\langle L_\beta\mid\beta<\alpha\rangle$ is $\Delta_1$-definable over $L_\alpha$, the problem reduces to proving the following one:

> If $a\in L_\alpha$ and $f\colon a\to \alpha$ is $\Sigma_1$-definable over $L_\alpha$, then $f$ is bounded.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to proceed from there. There might be some similar proof in textbooks about admissible set theory or higher computability (or fine structure theory), but I do not know which reference would be relevant. I would appreciate your help!

Comment: I think the usual definition of collection uses $f:a\to L_\alpha$, although when dealing with admissibility these are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

In fact we can get $\Sigma_1$-collection directly! The following argument is pulled from a set of handwritten notes by Ronald Jensen, which seems to be called "[Admissible Sets](https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/%7Eraesch/org/jensen/pdf/AS_3.pdf#page=14)". Jensen proves that failure of a strengthened (not just $\Sigma_1$-collection) version of admissibility implies failure of $\Sigma_1$-separation, so this is modified into the contrapositive direction.

Let $\alpha$ be such that $L_\alpha$ satisfies $\Sigma_1$-separation. Then assume there exists such a function $f:a\to L_\alpha$ whose range is not bounded by some member of $L_\alpha$. We may then construct the set $X=\{x\in a\mid x\notin f(x)\}$, which is a $\Sigma_1(L_\alpha)$ set. Since $f$'s range is unbounded in $L_\alpha$, $X$ is not necessarily present in any earlier $\textrm{Def}(L_\beta)$ for $\beta<\alpha$. Let $z\in a$ be such that $f(z)=X$, this should be possible to choose since $f$'s range is not restricted to any member of $X\subseteq L_\alpha$. Then using the usual diagonal argument, $z\in X\iff z\notin f(z)\iff z\notin X$, which is a contradiction. So $f$ couldn't have existed, and $L_\alpha$ satisfies $\Sigma_1$-collection.

Comment: Can you explain how you find such a $z$? From definition, you know that there is definitely some $z, Y$ such that $f(z)=Y$ and $X\subset Y$, since $f$ is unbounded. But how do you make sure $X$ itself is in the range?

Comment: @Shervin How about the following simpler argument? Suppose $f\colon a\to L_\alpha$ be an unbounded function in $\Sigma_1(L_\alpha)$. Its range is also $\Sigma_1$-definable, and is a member of $L_\alpha$ by $\Sigma_1$-separation over $L_\alpha$. However, every sets of ordinals in $\operatorname{Def}(L_\beta)$ is a subset of $\beta$, and $L_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}\operatorname{Def}(L_\beta)$, which means every sets of ordinals in $L_\alpha$ is bounded.

Comment: @HanulJeon, I don't see how you want to apply separation, because ultimately the range of $f$ might be an unbounded subset of $L_\alpha$ itself and you can't apply separation to a "class".

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Jensen left the actual value of $z$ out, only saying that some such $z$ exists. I had thought $z$ was such that $f(z)=X$, but now I think my idea may be wrong, since from there I don't know how Jensen got $z\in X$.

Comment: @HanulJeon If I understand, your comment assumes such an unbounded $\Sigma_1(L_\alpha)$ function exists (i.e. $\alpha$ is not admissible), then uses that to derive an instance of $\Sigma_1$-separation. This doesn't seem to be the goal we want to show

Comment: I admit my previous argument was incorrect, and what @Shervin pointed out is correct: there is no reason to apply $\Sigma_1$-separation to get the set I mentioned.

Comment: I am thinking about 'upgrading' a cofinal map $a\to \alpha$ to a surjection $a\to L_\alpha$. This is clear if we work with the Jensen hierarchy: if $\alpha$ is not admissible, then it has a $\Sigma_1(J_\alpha)$ onto map $\gamma\to J_\alpha$ for some $\gamma<\omega\cdot\alpha$ (Here I assume  $J_\alpha\cap\mathrm{Ord}=\omega\cdot\alpha$. See Lemma 2.11 of Jensen's *The Fine Structure of the constructible hierarchy*.) Then we can apply @C7X's argument. I am not sure it works for $L_\alpha$.

Comment: @HanulJeon I couldn't find this in Jensen's "The Fine Structure", but in Keith Devlin's writeup "[An Introduction to the Fine Structure of the Constructible Hierarchy](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/30905237.pdf#page=41)", theorem 45 states that for admissible $\alpha$, $J_\alpha=L_{\omega\alpha}$. Since all the $\alpha$ in this question are greater than $\omega$, $\alpha=\omega\alpha$ and your argument by for $J_\alpha$ works.

Comment: But $\alpha>\omega$ does not automatically mean $\alpha=\omega\alpha$, isn't it?

Comment: @HanulJeon Not in general, but for admissible $\alpha$, if $\alpha>\omega$ then $\alpha=\omega\alpha$. (Cf. "The Fine Structure of the Constructible Hierarchy", p.253). Also my earlier comment that I couldn't find the fact "$J_\alpha=L_{\omega\alpha}$" is easily solvable, it turned out to be right at the beginning of "Fine Structure"!